# Domain coloring of Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, riemann-zeta

[image: Riemann Zeta Function]

This is the domain coloring of Riemann zeta function. I do get the Re(z) < 1 part of the graph. However I am unsure why the Re(z) > 1 part of the graph is all red with the same brightness and hue. Why is this so?

Comment: It simply depends on the coloring chosen. For your picture above it was most probably the following coloring as your plot is also from wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannsche_%CE%B6-Funktion#/media/File:Complex_coloring.jpg

Comment: @YukiJ Yes, but shouldn't the red color get fainter as ||z|| gets bigger?

Comment: Check the x-axis of the plot. It ranges to 40 in your plot only. The coloring above starts fading for slightly bigger values than that.

Comment: @YukiJ Oh I forgot to check the range! Thank you (*'▽')

Comment: You could get a better understanding and perspective with this youtube video, > Visualizing the Riemann Zeta function. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw

Comment: Thank you for sharing a video. But I don't quite understand why the conformal map shown in the video looks symmetrical to Re(z) = c while the domain coloring of zeta function is not horizontally symmetrical at all. Could you give an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put my comments into a coherent form and answer:

The way the graph looks like depends on the coloring chosen. For your picture above it was most probably [this coloring](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannsche_%CE%B6-Funktion#/media/File:Complex_coloring.jpg) since your plot is also from wikipedia.

You will notice that the graph of the zeta function in your question is only depicted for values up to 40 on the $x$-axis. The coloring, however, starts changing for slightly bigger values than that only. So, in this domain the whole right side is red. If you plotted the zeta-function for values up to say 150 on the right you would see several differences. I hope this clarifies it.